# Windows Form to HTML

Tags: html, windows, winforms, excel, checkbox

I was just wondering, did some research on internet as well, is there anyway to export a windows form which is coded in VB as HTML. Doesn't need to be directly I mean it can go over from excel to HTML or any other route which is possible. I just want my user to tick couple of check boxes and see the text which I retrieved from my database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WPF is designed to handle this situation, not winforms.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15559/A-Windows-Forms-based-text-editor-with-HTML-output

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out that that I've seen that is a perfect solution.

I did see [this interesting article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9307/Converting-WinForms-Web-Forms-using-CodeDom) which looks like it does a rough job of it, and might be sufficient.

However, if it's that simple, and you already know how to code WInForms, you could just bite the bullet and create ASP.NET pages. (Using WebForms instead ov MCV as it's more similar)  The two programming/design models arean't really all that different.

Comment: I'm not interested in too many details actually all I want is my user to read some data which comes from database as text in a textbox or in a label and just click some checkboxes that's it no buttons or send requests etc. and I saw some codes changing form to excel format, do you think will it be possible to convert it to html from excel? like short story winfrom to excel, from excel to html?

Comment: It IS possible, using the Office APIs but FAR more difficult than looking up a tutorial on ASP.NET, and learning how to display the data using ASP.NET.

Answer (score -2):

there is a function in excel to export an datasheet to an HTML page.

SaveAs >>>> Html page or web page.

And the same goes for Word.

Good luck

Comment: This is `not an answer`. Read his question carefully.